# 'bullet centered' between examples in linguex

Tags: examples, linguex

I'm using `linguex` package for examples. In one of them I use a bullet in this way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{linguex}
\begin{document}
\ex.  $\lambda P. \lambda Q. (\textbf{but}(P)(Q)): \langle t \langle t, t \rangle \rangle$ \\ \hspace{20mm} $\bullet$ \\ $\lambda P. \lambda Q. (\textbf{but}(P)(Q)): \langle t \langle t, t \rangle \rangle + \rho \langle e, t \rangle $ 


\end{document}
```

I tried with a `\hspace` to make the bullet in between the two examples appears in the middle; but it didn't work.

How I can put the bullet at the center of those two examples.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to put everything inside of an `array` enviroment, like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{linguex}
\begin{document}
\ex.
$\begin{array}{c}
  \lambda P. \lambda Q. (\textbf{but}(P)(Q)): \langle t \langle t, t \rangle \rangle\\
  \bullet\\
  \lambda P. \lambda Q. (\textbf{but}(P)(Q)): \langle t \langle t, t \rangle \rangle + \rho \langle e, t \rangle
\end{array}$

\end{document}
```

The two lambda terms and the bullet form 3 rows of the array, which are centered (`{c}`).

Answer (score 1):

For the minimum change, you can use \hspace* (if you don't want the alignments of Brian's answer)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{linguex}
\begin{document}
\ex.  $\lambda P. \lambda Q. (\textbf{but}(P)(Q)): \langle t \langle t, t \rangle \rangle$ \\ \hspace*{20mm} $\bullet$ \\ $\lambda P. \lambda Q. (\textbf{but}(P)(Q)): \langle t \langle t, t \rangle \rangle + \rho \langle e, t \rangle $ 


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly different version of Brian Buccola's answer, which left aligns the lines and removes the intercolumn space but still centres the bullet. I've used the `array` package to make a column type for that.  I've also added a `[t]` alignment to the `array` environment so that it aligns properly with the example number:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{A}{@{}l@{}}
\newcommand{\cbull}{\multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}}{\bullet}}
\begin{document}
\ex.
$\begin{array}[t]{A}
  \lambda P. \lambda Q. (\textbf{but}(P)(Q)): \langle t \langle t, t \rangle \rangle\\
  \cbull\\
  \lambda P. \lambda Q. (\textbf{but}(P)(Q)): \langle t \langle t, t \rangle \rangle + \rho \langle e, t \rangle
\end{array}$

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]